# Subtracting sets within a grouped column, should I be pivoting?

Tags: postgresql, pivot

I'm not the best at explaining, but I have a table that has the format

```
CREATE TABLE foo
AS
  SELECT type,date::date,tp,price
  FROM ( VALUES
    ( 'A', '2010-10-01', 1, 0.05 ),
    ( 'A', '2010-10-01', 2, 1.04 ),
    ( 'B', '2010-10-01', 1, 0.53 ),
    ( 'B', '2010-10-01', 2, 1.04 ),
    ( 'C', '2010-10-01', 1, 0.05 ),
    ( 'C', '2010-10-01', 2, 1.02 ),
    ( 'D', '2010-10-01', 1, 0.05 ),
    ( 'D', '2010-10-01', 2, 1.08 )
  ) AS t(type,date,tp,price);
```

And what I want to do is subtract different types where the date and tp are the same. So that would be A-B, A-C, A-D, B-A, B-C, B-D, C-A, C-B, C-D, D-A, D-B, D-C.

To me this seems like I would want a wide format table, with the columns `date, tp, A, B, C, D` and then do a column-wise subtraction based on possible combinations. If the subtraction is less than 0, then the value is 0

The desired output looks something like this:

```
combo | date      | tp | price
---+------------+----+-------
A_B  | 2010-10-01 | 1  | 0
A_B  | 2010-10-01 | 2  | 0
A_C  | 2010-10-01 | 1  | 0
A_C  | 2010-10-01 | 2  | 0.02
A_D  | 2010-10-01 | 1  | 0
A_D  | 2010-10-01 | 2  | 0
and so on for all the combinations
```

Should I be looking at using `crosstab` ? Or is there a simpler/more elegant solution? My current solution is a view that uses CTE(s) to create all the possible dates and type combos, and then I have a function that goes through every typeA and typeB, date, tp combo. It is very slow.

The initial table in question is 2857658 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Simple self-join

What you want is something like this...

```
SELECT
  ARRAY[f1.type,f2.type] AS type,
  date,
  tp,
  greatest(f1.price-f2.price, '0.00') AS price
FROM foo AS f1
INNER JOIN foo AS f2
  USING (date, tp)
WHERE f1.type <> f2.type
ORDER BY f1.type, f2.type, tp;
```

I deviated a bit from what you desired. Generally, you don't want string concatenation like that. It's less useful. You're better off using an array. If you do want string concatenation just use `f1.type || '_' || f2.type`.

```
 type  |    date    | tp | price 
-------+------------+----+-------
 {A,B} | 2010-10-01 |  1 |  0.00
 {A,B} | 2010-10-01 |  2 |  0.00
 {A,C} | 2010-10-01 |  1 |  0.00
 {A,C} | 2010-10-01 |  2 |  0.02
 {A,D} | 2010-10-01 |  1 |  0.00
 {A,D} | 2010-10-01 |  2 |  0.00
 ...
 (24 rows)
```

## Crosstab

Cross-tab does something totally different. It only ever changes the display.

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab($$
  SELECT
    ARRAY[f1.type,f2.type] AS type,
    date,
    tp,
    greatest(f1.price-f2.price, '0.00') AS price
  FROM foo AS f1
  INNER JOIN foo AS f2
    USING (date, tp)
  WHERE f1.type <> f2.type
  ORDER BY f1.type, f2.type, tp;
$$, $$VALUES (1),(2)$$
) AS t(type text[],"date" date,tp1 numeric,tp2 numeric);
```

Produces...

```
 type  |    date    | tp1  | tp2  
-------+------------+------+------
 {A,B} | 2010-10-01 | 0.00 | 0.00
 {A,C} | 2010-10-01 | 0.00 | 0.02
 {A,D} | 2010-10-01 | 0.00 | 0.00
 {B,A} | 2010-10-01 | 0.48 | 0.00
 {B,C} | 2010-10-01 | 0.48 | 0.02
 {B,D} | 2010-10-01 | 0.48 | 0.00
 {C,A} | 2010-10-01 | 0.00 | 0.00
 {C,B} | 2010-10-01 | 0.00 | 0.00
 {C,D} | 2010-10-01 | 0.00 | 0.00
 {D,A} | 2010-10-01 | 0.00 | 0.04
 {D,B} | 2010-10-01 | 0.00 | 0.04
 {D,C} | 2010-10-01 | 0.00 | 0.06
(12 rows)
```

12 rows rather than 24. We pivoted and put `tp1`, and `tp2` together. Pick your poison -- what kind of display do you want? I always prefer not using cross tab unless someone requires it.

## Performance questions

> My current solution is a view that uses CTE(s) to create all the possible dates and type combos, and then I have a function that goes through every typeA and typeB, date, tp combo. It is very slow.

We would need to actually see the views, and to an output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to know why it runs slow. Try the query I suggested at the top and see if it speeds things up.